SwiftUI TextEditor View not searchable on macOS?
First time using TextEditor in a macOS project.
According to this:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-find-and-replace-text
my code should give me built-in Search / Search& Replace, but when I run and hit cmd-F,  all I hear is the system "Tok" sound and do nothing.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = "blah blach blach"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .navigationTitle("Edit Bio")
        }
    }
}

Am I missing something? Already tried this on Apple Silicon and Intel Macs both running Sonoma, same result and building on Xcode 15.3.

The article you linked talks about iOS, where find & replace is indeed built into TextEditor without needing any extra code.
On macOS, you can add TextEditingCommands to your scene to enable this:
@main
struct FooApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            TextEditingCommands()
        }
    }
}

